# Laravel 5.4 Control DB info language with controller

Tags: laravel, locale

I have task to put in DB some events with date/time and description in 3 languages. So i made Table with fields -> datetime, RU, LV, EN.

I can put information in to DB and so far all is great. But now i have problem to control description output in selected language. I made it work with controling that in blade, but not sure that this is good practice, so i would like to know how to control information in controller.

Here is controller:

```
  public function mafia(){


    $games = Mafiagame::all();
    //if(App::isLocale('lv')){

    //  $game = DB::table('mafiagames')->pluck('lv');

    //}
    //elseif(App::isLocale('en')){

    //  $game = DB::table('mafiagames')->pluck('en');

    //}
    //elseif(App::isLocale('ru')){

    //  $game = DB::table('mafiagames')->pluck('ru');

    //}
    //  $gametime = DB::table('mafiagames')->pluck('gametime');
    return view ('pages.mafia')->with('games', $games);
}
```

As you see those comments are my trying to create something for my goal....

Here is Blade :

```
  @if (count($games) >0)
                @foreach ($games as $games)
                    <div class ="info_area col-12">
                        <p>
                            {{$games->gametime}}
                        </p>
                        @if (App::isLocale('en'))
                            <p>
                            {{$games->en}}
                            </p>
                        @elseif (App::isLocale('ru'))
                            <p>
                            {{$games->ru}}
                            </p>
                        @elseif (App::isLocale('lv'))
                            <p>
                            {{$games->lv}}
                            </p>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wrong approach here and not using laravel's built-in feature for multilingual uses.

There is a translation section that you can use, for multiple languages, and it's not stored in the database. What I think you should do is store a generic/common-ground in the database (english wording and UTC date for example), and output the information by using translation and assessors.

References below

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

I like to think that:

1. Someone submits information to an endpoint
2. Request goes to a formvalidation, to validate it's content
3. It enters the controller
4. Apply the logic required
5. Return a response

The output, it's the responsability of the requester, which in this case would be the View (blade) part. If you want, however, to translate inside the controller, that's fine aswell, it all depends on your final purpose.

Comment: Most of my page content is using translated files with localization but there will be new contend added by admin and in that case i must put in DB all possible translations and after that take them from there